# size(SharedPartitionedTable)=0 in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

```
sym = `C`MS`MS`MS`IBM`IBM`C`C`C
price= 49.6 29.46 29.52 30.02 174.97 175.23 50.76 50.32 51.29
qty = 2200 1900 2100 3200 6800 5400 1300 2500 8800
timestamp = [09:34:07,09:36:42,09:36:51,09:36:59,09:32:47,09:35:26,09:34:16,09:34:26,09:38:12]
t=Table(timestamp,sym,price,qty)
db=database("",VALUE,09:32:00..09:40:00)
pt=db.createPartitionedTable(t,`pt,`timestamp)
pt.append!(t)
share(pt,`sharet)
size(pt)
```

result=0

I want to know the reason why size(pt)=0.

Answer (score 0):

Users must use sql query to have acccess to a shared partitioned in-memory table.